# android database copy error through programming

Tags: android, database

I have a strange problem I am trying to copy database from asset folder to app database folder  "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/" by the below code. this is working fine for Samsung mobile not working for gionee mobile I don't know why please help

```
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput =            myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate the `DB_PATH`? Maybe it is not available on the gionee mobile device (because the manufacturer modded the OS).

You should use the code below to determine `outFileName`:

```
String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
```

If that still throws an exception, please update your post with more details.

Comment: Hi My db path is"/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/" I suppose this default database path for android . I want to add one more thing if I write getreadabledatabase() I get error couldn't open database error 14

Comment: Well, that the path is "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/" on each and every device, in each and every android version, and on each and every android fork is a pretty strong assumption. Not saying this has to be the source of the problem, but I would strongly advise using ``getDatabasePath`` instead. This will also make your code more robust and future proof as you rely less on 'magic constants' and more on the framework.

Comment: Ok @chris will make the changes and let you know on Monday as this project is my office project and source code is in office

Comment: I have used your technique and found out database path is correct

Comment: Ok, then please add the stacktrace of your exception on the gionee mobile device to your original post. Maybe it elaborates a bit what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry for late reply I was very busy with project. The issue was resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling the app dont exactly know what went wrong

Comment: Glad you found a way to fix the issue :-)